# getting Id in apex controller without using standard controller ApexPages.StandardController

Tags: apex, controller, url

I have one apex page IncForRep that rerefs a controller IncForRep. i have used
this constructor

```
public IncForRep(ApexPages.StandardController a){..}
```

to use `Id i=a.getRecord().get('id');` . I want to get the id from the URL of this page. https://c.cs7.visual.force.com/apex/IncForRep?RepId=005A0000001LvaqIAC in my method.

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not able to incorporate the constructor with the page. Error : Unknown constructor 'IncForRep.IncForRep()

Comment: believe you having an extension controller instead of a custom controller. for extension controllers you need to have ApexPages.StandardController as  a parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below code to get the parameters from the URL

```
ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('RepId');
```

UPDATE :
based on the error message you posted, it seems you are having an extension controller instead of a custom controller.

for [extension controllers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm) you need to have ApexPages.StandardController as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: I'm not able to incorporate the constructor with the page. Error : Unknown constructor 'IncForRep.IncForRep()

Comment: can you post your complete controller code

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id');`